# how can i remove waydroid repositories?

Tags: apt, repository

I couldn't find the waydroid repository in `Software & Updates > Other Software`
So where is the waydroid repository stored?

Comment: Did you manually add this repository to your system?

Comment: @matigo yes i did

Comment: How did you add it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For someone who has the same problem, I was able to remove waydroid repositories with this method:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/keyrings/waydroid.gpg
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/waydroid.list
```

Comment: Why `-rf`? What will those flags accomplish?

Comment: @user535733 It was a mistake, thank you for reminding me.